# Failing to login to Laravel-admin panel after deploying to C panel

Tags: laravel, laravel-admin

I have a site using laravel-admin package. Login works fine on localhost, but once deployed to C Panel, its not login and they is now a message in my form *This form is not secure. Auto fill have been disabled*

[Login Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FaRbK.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to submit the form from http whilst you have hosted the web over https. Open laravel config/admin file and change the https config to true see  image below
[image]

Comment: Try this hope it will work on yours it worked on mine